# BigQuery: group counters by month after self-join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have table that looks like this:

[image: My table]

I'm trying to build a query, that will show specific partnerId counters groupped by keywordName and *month*. 
To solve first part(without grouping by month), I've built this query:

```
SELECT keywordName, COUNT(keywordName) as total, IFNULL(b.ebay_count, 0) as ebay, IFNULL(c.amazon_count, 0) as amazon,
    FROM LogFilesv2_Dataset.FR_Clickstats_v2 a
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT keywordName as kw , SUM(CASE WHEN partnerId='eBay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ebay_count
      FROM LogFilesv2_Dataset.FR_Clickstats_v2
      WHERE partnerId = 'eBay' GROUP BY kw) b
  ON keywordName = b.kw
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT keywordName as kw , SUM(CASE WHEN partnerId='AmazonApi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as amazon_count
      FROM LogFilesv2_Dataset.FR_Clickstats_v2
      WHERE partnerId = 'AmazonApi' GROUP BY kw) c
  ON keywordName = c.kw

WHERE keywordName = 'flipper' -- just to filter out single kw. 
GROUP BY keywordName, ebay, amazon
```

It works quite well and returns following output:

[image: query result]

Now I'm trying to make additional group by month, but all my attempts returned incorrect results.
Final output supposed to be similar to this:

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    date_trunc(dt, month) dt,
    keywordName,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when partnerId = 'eBay' then 1 else 0 end) ebay,
    sum(case when partnerId = 'AmazonApi' then 1 else 0 end) amazon
from LogFilesv2_Dataset.FR_Clickstats_v2
group by date_trun(dt, month), keywordName
```